# How is inner product addition performed?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

The Swap test proof on page 8 of https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~vandam/teaching/S05_CS290/week9.pdf ends with this derivation:[image]

How you add those inner products to get from $\frac{1}{4}(2 + \langle \Psi, \varphi|\Psi, \varphi\rangle + \langle\varphi, \Psi|\Psi,\varphi\rangle)$

to 
$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} (|\Psi|\varphi\rangle|)^2 $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
    \Pr(\text{“0"}) & =
    \frac{1}{4} ( 2 + \left\langle \psi , \phi \mid \phi, \psi \right\rangle + \left\langle \phi , \psi \mid \psi , \phi \right\rangle ) \\
    & = \frac{1}{4} ( 2 + \left\langle \psi \mid \phi \right\rangle \left\langle\phi \mid \psi\right\rangle + \left\langle \phi \mid \psi \right\rangle \left\langle\psi \mid \phi\right\rangle )\\
    & = \frac{1}{4} ( 2 + | \left\langle \psi \mid \phi \right\rangle |^2 + | \left\langle \phi \mid \psi \right\rangle|^2)\\
    & = \frac{1}{4} ( 2 + 2 | \left\langle \psi \mid \phi \right\rangle |^2 )\\
    & = \frac{1}{2} ( 1 + 1 | \left\langle \psi \mid \phi \right\rangle |^2 )\\
\end{align}
$$

Edit:

$$
| \left\langle \psi \mid \phi \right\rangle |^2 = | \left\langle \phi \mid \psi \right\rangle|^2
$$
Inside the norm squared, the 2 quantities inside are complex conjugates of each other. So they have the same norm squared.

Comment: I don't see how

 $| < \psi \mid \phi > |^2 + | < \phi \mid \psi >|^2$ = $2 | < \psi \mid \phi > |^2$

Comment: @VictoryOmole: For a complex number $z$, $|z|^2$ is defined as $zz^*$, where $z^*$ is the complex conjugate of $z$. Note, however, that $\left\langle \psi | \phi \right\rangle^* = \left\langle \phi | \psi \right\rangle$. Thus, $|\left\langle \psi | \phi \right\rangle|^2 = \left\langle \psi | \phi \right\rangle \left\langle \phi | \psi \right\rangle$.